# Render Component in loop, use Index in method of child component (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I have two components where some exchange of props takes place. Props is the whole todo array, which is updated by a click on the button with the "addTodo" method. Passing the array down to the child works fine. I can display the props dynamically in my p-tags, but it seems to be not possible to use it my the methods of my child component.

```vue
    <template>
      <v-app>
        <v-content>
          <h2>Add a Todo</h2>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
            <v-text-field label="Regular" v-model="text"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <div class="my-3">
            <v-btn medium @click="addTodo">Add Todo</v-btn>
          </div>
          <div v-for="(todo, index) in todos" v-bind:key="index">
            <HelloWorld
              v-bind:todos="todos"
              v-bind:index="index"
              v-bind:class="(todos[index].done)?'green':'red'"
            />
          </div>
        </v-content>
      </v-app>
    </template>

    <script>
    import HelloWorld from "./components/ToDo.vue";

    export default {
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
          text: "",
          todos: []
        };
      },
      methods: {
        addTodo() {
          this.todos.push({
            text: this.text,
            done: false
          });
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

This is my child component

```vue
    <template>
      <v-card max-width="250">
        <v-card-text>
          <h2 class="text-center">{{todos[index].text}}</h2>
          <p class="display-1 text--primary"></p>
          <p>{{index}}</p>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn text color="deep-purple accent-4" @click="done"></v-btn>
          <v-btn text color="orange accent-4">Delete Task</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      props: ["todos", "index"],
      methods: {
        done() {
          this.todos[1].text = "bla";
        }
      }
    };
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    .seperator {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    </style>
```

I pass a whole array with objects as props, and using the index inside the p-tag works fine, but I also want to use it like this:

```js
      methods: {
        done() {
          this.todos[index].text = "bla";
        }
      }
```

> 'index' is not defined

Everything works fine, but I am not able use the index value inside the method. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried with `this.index`?

Comment: *＋1* for keeping the site tidy.

Answer (score 0):

The way you write it out, there is nothing in scope defining index. Where is that value coming from?

Index is a prop and so it must be referenced with `this`.

```
done () {
     this.todos[this.index].text = 'bla'
}
```